# iOS: How can you change the color of a part of UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

In the Nike app on iOS if you customize a shoe somehow they let you select different colors for different sections of the shoes (midsole red, or tongue green for example).  I am wondering how do you do this on iOS? The shapes are pretty irregular so making a Bezier curve seems unlikely.  The image doesn't move either so it doesn't seem like they are swapping images.  Does anyone have any clue about a way to do is?

One thing I did notice is the images is fuzzy when you make a change and then comes into focus after a delay but not sure if that is a clue or not. :shrug:

Here is an example

[grey toe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVx2b.png)

[black toe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFpzc.png)

Comment: Do not evade the closing of you question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68092051/ios-how-can-you-change-the-color-of-a-subsection-of-uiimage by asking it again.

Comment: My intention was to clarify the question, not evade.

Answer (score 0):

They are swapping images, in fact they are all fetched when entering this screen. So they are all  present on the memory when swapping between them, that's why it seems that they are changing colors.

Comment: So you believe they are all the permutations of all the color combos and they are just switching between them each time you select a color for a section??? Possible but the fact that images are fuzzy and then get clearer makes me disagree.  If they were just swapping images they would have the same clarity as soon as the fetch and load finishes.